# Adding a number to a date

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

What I need to do is in my program i need to add the Arrival DATE and the Nights staying together and have it display into another textbox called Departure date. The format for the arrival date will be in the "##/##/##" context and the nights staying is an integer between 1 and 14.

I have all of the code for the rest of my program completed, I just do not know how to do this. I dont know how to take an integer and add it to a date so in the display box, after they are added together, it displays a date X amount of days after the arrival days. Where X is the Nights staying.

I Will greatly appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.AddDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to add number of days in the `DateTime` object like:

```
DateTime arrivalDate = new DateTime(2014,03,10); 

DateTime departureDate = arrivalDate.AddDays(1); // Add One day
```

To get the formatted Date back use `ToString` with [Custom DateTime Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string formattedDate = departureDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: How do I go about adding this to my textbox? If say the date is 4/1/2014 and the staying number is 4. How would I add 4 days do the date selected in another box?

Comment: First you need a `DateTime` object for your original date, You can parse the text `4/1/2014` to `DateTime` object using `DateTime.ParseExact` like `DateTime dtArrival = DateTime.ParseExact( "4/1/2014", "M/d/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` and then `DateTime dtDepartureDate = dtArrival.AddDays(4)`. This would give you a new date object with 4 days added to it. Later you can use it in your textbox like `TextBoxDeparture.Text = dtDeparture.ToString("M/d/yyyy");`